# How to create a new window

Tags: javascript, window, tidesdk

I need to create a new top level window or a child window based on the action of the user and i'm using javascript to know the action that has been taken. I'm using the Ti.UI.createWindow() for this and I have tried it with all the possible variations of it i.e null, sending the url, sending the options object but I couldn't get result from any of them. Could anyone show me how to create both a new top-level window and a child-window, I know it sounds silly but I can't get it to work. I'm using Tide SDK 1.3.1 beta on windows 7

P.S: The Ti.UI.currentWindow is working fine and I could change the width and height by using the set methods.

Comment: A small clarification regarding my "P.S" I can work the attributes of a window using the Ti.UI.currentWindow but I can't seem to create a new child window or a new top window or may be i'm missing something.....your help would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out that to create a new child window we need to use the "open()" method after the createWindow() call.

Example:
    `Ti.UI.createWindow("app://example.html").open();`

Comment: Yes it looks like app:// is required before the url for it to work

Answer (score 0):

`Ti.UI.createWindow` is the way to go. You also need to actually "show" a created window, for it to show up, maybe you forgot to do that?

Example:

```
var new_window = Ti.UI.createWindow("example.html");
new_window.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex and I did try what you said but no output what-so-ever :|

Comment: .show() doesn't seem to work at all but .open() does